# Divide a number by numbers from a list

Tags: python-3.x, math

I have this script, it outputs this list of numbers after running

```
x = 542357098500868790
y = 0
while x > y:
    print(x)
    
    x = x // 108
```

**Result**

```
542357098500868790
5021824986119155
46498379501103
430540550936
3986486582
36911912
341776
3164
29
```

I want to create a list of numbers like "108,109,110,111 and so on, so that the script takes a number from the script and divides it by what is in the list and saves the result in one file or displays everything on the screen, so that it looks like this

```
542357098500868790
5021824986119155
46498379501103
430540550936
3986486582
36911912
341776
3164
29

542357098500868790
4975753197255676
45649111901428
418799191756
3842194419
35249490
323389
2966
27
```

Answer (score -1):

this is a good opportunity to use lists and a for loop.

```
nums = [108, 109, 110, 111]
for div in nums:
    x = 542357098500868790
    y = 0
    while x > y:
        print(x)
        x = x // div
```

Alternatively use the range function to generate a range of numbers like so:

```
nums = range(108,112)
```